# Financial Data Simulator

Tags: machine-learning, simulator, prediction

I have been asked to develop a financial data simulator as a app for my year end project.The app would be able to predict stock market prices based on past time series data,historic values etc.Basically I have to develop one such algorithm
I am wondering what programming languages and methods should I start learning?
Or any books should I be reading?
Thanks a lot
Iam an undergraduate student by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [R language](http://www.r-project.org/) and [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package.  Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885828/forecasting-with-ets-results) SO question as well.

It also has some nice graphs features implemented. 
[Here's](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) more info on time series forecasting.